# Redirect after token validation in Vue.js from Login Page to Dashboard

Tags: javascript, vue.js, authentication, redirect, token

I would like to redirect my User to the dashboard page if the user has token with it. But the code is unable to perform redirection. I am generating a JWT token from my Spring Boot backend and sending it as a response to the Vue for processing

```
    import { setupLayouts } from 'virtual:generated-layouts'
    import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
    import { isUserLoggedIn } from './utils'
    import routes from '~pages'
    import { canNavigate } from '@layouts/plugins/casl'

    const router = createRouter({
      history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
      routes: [
        {
          path: '/',
          redirect: to => {
            const userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('accessToken') || '{}')

            console.log(userData)
            if (userData)
              return { name: 'pages-misc-coming-soon' }
            else
              return { name: 'login', query: to.query }
          },
        },
        {
          path: '/pages/user-profile',
          redirect: () => ({ name: 'pages-user-profile-tab', params: { tab: 'profile' } }),
        },
        {
          path: '/pages/account-settings',
          redirect: () => ({ name: 'pages-account-settings-tab', params: { tab: 'account' } }),
        },
        ...setupLayouts(routes),
      ],
    })

    router.beforeEach(to => {
      const isLoggedIn = isUserLoggedIn()

      if (canNavigate(to)) {
        if (to.meta.redirectIfLoggedIn && isLoggedIn)
          return '/'
      }
      else {
        if (isLoggedIn)
          return { name: 'not-authorized' }
        else
          return { name: 'login', query: { to: to.name !== 'index' ? to.fullPath : undefined } }
      }
    })

    export default router
```

Comment: which part of the code doesn't do what you expect?

Comment: if (userData)
              return { name: 'pages-misc-coming-soon' }
            else
              return { name: 'login', query

Comment: guess you could do `if (Object.keys(userData).length) {` instead (based on the answer below that identifies the issue perfectly)

Answer (score 1):

empty json ( {} ) is truthy.

run this:

```
if(JSON.parse('{}')) {console.log('11') } else {console.log('22')}
```